# Object counting copy constructor called more times than the destructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, destructor

I have in this class Transaction a multimap in which I store dated transactions (I have another Date class). When the object is instantiated it will be automatically added into the multimap .

The problem is that in the main function, after I instantiate an object, the number of transactions is 2 instead of 1.

The copy constructor is called 2 times because of the multimap insertion and the destructor is called only once.

How can I solve that, besides decrementing again the number of transactions in the constructor?

```
class Transaction {
private:
    std::string note;
    float value;
    Date date;
    static unsigned int numberOfTransactions;
    static std::multimap<Date, Transaction, Date::Comparator> datedTransactions;

public:
    Transaction( Date date, std::string note, float value )
      {
        std::cout<<"Constructor is called";
        this->date = date;
        this->note = note;
        this->value = value;
        datedTransactions.insert(std::make_pair(date, *this));
    }

    ~Transaction() {
        std::cout<<"Destructor is called";
        numberOfTransactions--;
    }

    Transaction( Transaction const & t ) {
        std::cout<<std::endl<<"Copy constructor is called";
        note = t.note;
        value = t.value;
        numberOfTransactions++;
    }

    Transaction& operator=(Transaction const &t) {
        if (this != &t) {
            note = t.note;
            value = t.value;
        }
    }

    static unsigned int GetNumberOfTransactions() {
        return numberOfTransactions;
    }
};

int main() { // main should return int & not void
    Date date;
    Transaction (date, "dinner", 100);
    std::cout << std::endl << Transaction::GetNumberOfTransactions() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How about showing the code which does the insertion?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: oh..yeah sorry. it is in the constructor.

Comment: The title of your post says nothing about the question is the post. Can you fix it please?

Comment: I do not see any "main" function

Comment: The one issue that sticks out to me is that in the User Defined Constructor in the initializer list you are setting a member variable named `transactionId` that doesn't exist in your class as a member...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep track of all objects of your class, you have to instrument *all* of its constructors, including the copy (and move) constructor.

What's happening is:

1. A `Transaction` object is created using the constructor you've provided.
2. `datedTransactions.insert(std::make_pair(date, *this));` creates a temporary `Transaction` object (inside the pair) using the copy constructor of your class.
3. A new `Transaction` object inside the map is initialised by a move constructor from the temporary.
4. The temporary is destroyed, which is the destructor you see triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have a copy constructor, so any temporary `Transaction` objects that get created by copying won't be inserted into the map, but will still decrease the counter when they are destroyed.

If you have a non-trivial destructor you **always** need to consider how to correctly define copy constructor and copy-assignment operator. Read about [the rule of five](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-five).

To solve your problem you could add a `bool` flag to the class that is only set to true for objects that are inserted into the map, and is false for any copies. Then in the destructor only decrease the counter if the flag is true.